# create form $post and on submit it sumbit the user id

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, post

I have 2 tables users & request,,, users works fine i can get the user id, im using userspice 4, i created the table named request, i created another form method post and created the insert.

```
<?php

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxa", "xxxxx", "xxxx");
 if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }

 // Escape user inputs for security
  $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['fname']);
  $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lname']);
  $amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['amount']);
 $cedula = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['cedula']);
```

// attempt insert query execution

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO request (fname, lname, amount, cedula )    VALUES      ('$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[amount]','$_POST[cedula]')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
  echo "Records added successfully.";
  } else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
  }

  // close connection
 mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

now it works i got insert into my table, but i need also to  insert the user id at the submission moment, the form is located on user's account page, i need to submit the info along with the user id, so later on I can fetch based on user id, please help, i been searching around but can't find anything

Comment: Try storing the user ID as a session.

Comment: If i get what you want to do, you should create fk in your request table and make relation between two tables

Comment: The logged in user's id is available to you on every page using $user->data()->id;

Answer (score 0):

Try to store userid in session and use it at the time of insert.Dont forgot to start session.

Storing in user's account page

```
$_SESSION['userid']=$userid; //your userid variable
```

At the time of fetching

```
$userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
```

For more information about session  Check below link
[PHP SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: but how will i add this to my sert                                                                   VALUES      ('$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[amount]','$_POST[cedula]' , '$userid=$_SESSION['userid']')" is it something like this..i will like to know exactly how to create the submit

Comment: this is calling my id <?=$user->data()->id?> how get this into to session

Comment: use post values same way how you did for other page. for session value store like this way `$_SESSION['userid']=$user->data()->id ; // variable name `  To fetch on `$userid=$_SESSION['userid'];` and use `$userid` variable for insert query

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to save your request and user id so you get that request based on user id. If so you should create attribute  'user_id' in table 'request' and make relation between 'user id' from 'users' table and 'user id' from 'requests' table. So every time you insert request you connect that request to user who requested it.

Comment: i have it but what is happening is that when i do submit the user_id table is empty

Comment: I assume you initialize user_id var somewhere. And that you add user id in insert querry (in request table)? And why do you use post directly in input query when u created variable for input?

Comment: because for some reason it was entering the data without post in variable, or maybe i was doing something wrong

Comment: Did u fix it? If you did not can you send structure or er model of your table? And what error do u get when u try to insert user_id in request table?

Comment: sorry for the delay yes i follow instruction but now i'm getting this     Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`c0newloan`.`request`, CONSTRAINT `loan_requtes` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

Comment: You're not using the userspice classes to do these queries so it's a lot harder than it has to be. Please feel free to post in the userspice forums if you're still stuck.